# error 403 Forbidden taobao parsing

Tags: php, parsing, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse taobao, [product card](https://world.taobao.com/item/556926591992.html)

the data is [here](https://detailskip.taobao.com/json/dyn_combo.do?_ksTS=1506103975972_652&callback=jsonp653&&itemId=556926591992&rcid=30&price=18900&shopId=&itemId=556926591992&sellerId=2452161898&sellerId=2452161898&sellerId=2452161898&sellerId=2452161898&sellerId=2452161898&itemId=556926591992&al=false&ap=0&ss=0&free=1&itemId=556926591992&itemId=556926591992&databiz=promotionPrice,upp,bonuscoupon,shopbonuscoupon,shopbonuscoupon,shopcoupon,sidebarcoupon,overseaNewDelivery,dynStock,overseaViewer,contract,activitySwitch,buycount&u_channel=undefined)

In the browser, the data page is loaded normally:
[image]

[image]

But at the transition I get 403 Forbidden:

[image]

How can I work around this limitation with php
help please, very much need customers complain

Comment: Please consider adding some of the relevant code so that we can better help!

Comment: sorry, I did not know the English language asked a question, because I do not know where to turn anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

detailskip.taobao.com/json/dyn_combo.do blocks any request that doesn't have a "referrer" header pointing to another detailskip.taobao.com url. note that the referrer doesn't have to be real, you can just fake it, they don't actually validate it, the header just has to be there. also, they block any request with "php" in the user-agent header. also they block any request that doesn't have a user-agent header.

example code faking the referrer header and user-agent to get the json (using [my hhb_curl library](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/raw/master/hhb_.inc.php) as a error detecting wrapper around curl_ functions):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
header ( "content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8" );
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$json = (new hhb_curl ( '', true ))->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://detailskip.taobao.com/json/dyn_combo.do?itemId=556926591992&databiz=promotionPrice,upp,bonuscoupon,shopbonuscoupon,shopbonuscoupon,shopcoupon,sidebarcoupon,overseaNewDelivery,dynStock,overseaViewer,contract,activitySwitch,buycount',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'curl/7.52.1',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Referer: https://world.taobao.com/item/556926591992.html' 
        ) 
) )->exec ()->getStdOut();
echo $json;
```

Comment: why then do I get an error:
 Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /home/n/domen/domen/public_html/hhb_.inc.php on line 2

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home/n/domen/domen/public_html/hhb_.inc.php on line 9

Comment: @newProgrammer because this code is written for PHP7, and you're trying to run it in PHP5. you really should upgrade, PHP7's typehints is a blessing

Comment: if run, php7 will have problems with other pieces of code

Comment: @newProgrammer there's a PHP5 version of hhb_curl here https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php5.php - but it shouldn't be difficult to port it to PHP5 curl_  anyway

Comment: Thank you very much, you really helped, I am behind technology, but well that there is stackoverflow and such people

Comment: Sometimes it happens, displays a void, but it also displays error 500, is this normal?

Comment: @newProgrammer no, that is not normal. when its a 500 error, what is in your php error logs?

Comment: this: https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840526/v840526690/aa6a/rjRy_z02JGw.jpg

Comment: @newProgrammer that is just a slow reply, seems the target server was lagging for some reason. add CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>10 , and you give it 10 seconds to load, instead of the standard 4 seconds

Comment: and thought, but did not consider that the timeout default is 4 seconds, thank you amended

Answer (score 1):

what are you unable to parse, exactly? i have no problem parsing the product price and product name,

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
$html = file_get_contents ( 'https://world.taobao.com/item/556926591992.html' );
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
$name = $xp->query ( '//span[@itemprop="name"]' )->item ( 0 )->textContent;
$price = trim ( preg_replace ( '/\s+/u', ' ', $xp->query ( '//div[contains(@class,"price-show") and not(contains(@class,"hidden"))]' )->item ( 0 )->textContent ) );
var_dump ( $name, $price );
```

output:

```
 string(82) "欧美高街bf风潮牌oversize宽松男女嘻哈hiphop套头卫衣情侣装外套"
 string(9) "¥ 189.00"
```

(and protip, curl would run much faster due to it's understanding of content-length whereas file_get_contents only reads until the socket is closed, and curl would use considerably less bandwidth if you used CURLOPT_ENCODING, because this website and curl supports gzip compressed transfers which file_get_contents doesn't support, and curl wouldn't depend on the `allow_url_fopen` php.ini setting, which file_get_contents requires)

Comment: The parser does not need the site itself: `https://world.taobao.com/item/556926591992.html` and the data source: `https://detailskip.taobao.com/json/dyn_combo.do`

Comment: @newProgrammer most likely, https://world.taobao.com/item/556926591992.html generates an unique csrf-token in the html and a cookie session id that you must download, parse out, and supply to https://detailskip.taobao.com/json/dyn_combo.do - but again, what data are you after?

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c841226/v841226308/22745/_Jiz2fGvVzo.jpg discounts are already downloaded, through: `https://detailskip.taobao.com/json/dyn_combo.do`